ProcessPoolExecutor fails
I have a simple setup to test parallel execution, but it fails no matter what I've tried. I'm working in a Jupyter Notebook.
Here is a model example:
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def worker(i):
    print(f"TASK: {i}")
    result = i * i
    print(f"RESULT: {result}")
    return result


futures = []

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        for i in range(10):
            futures.append(executor.submit(worker, i))

    for i, future in enumerate(futures):
        try:
            result = future.result()
            print(result)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error in future {i}: {e}")

I have way more than 4 cores available, no memory issues, but it fails no matter what I try.
Error in future 0: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
(and so on for the other futures)

Solution:
Move worker into a python file and import it, then it works fine.

The program works for me (prints diagnostic messages, and then prints the squares of numbers in range(10)). I ran it in Python 3.12.4. Number of cores available, as far as I know, should not make any difference.

can't reproduce this (python 3.12.4 on macOS , linux mint 20.1), increased range from 10 through 100 ....

sorry, I should have mentioned it's in a Jupyter environment. Once I implemented it in a Python script file, everything worked fine. Once I clarified my environment, Google quickly found a solution.

It never ceases to amaze me how many problems people have with Jupyter. Just search stackoverflow and you'll see what I mean. I struggle to see its benefits. Maybe I should read a Jupyter tutorial. Or maybe I won't bother

The problem is this is trying to run in a Jupyter Notebook. The solution is to move worker into a python file and import it, then everything works fine.
